# How can i enable/use JSON_EXTRACT method in SQLite, PostgreSQL and MSSQL databases using laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel, sqlite

Want to enable/use/alternative method of JSON_EXTRACT which work same as JSON_EXTRACT in SQLite, PostgreSQL, MySQL and MSSQL databases using laravel.

Below query is working in **MySQL**, where `table2`.`attribute_data` is column of json data.

```
    $query->select('table1.*');
    $query->where(function ($q) use ($locale) {
        $q->where(Db::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(`table2`.`attribute_data`, "$.title")'), '!=', "");
        $q->where('table2.locale', '=', $locale);
    });
    $query->join('table2', function ($join) use ($locale) {
        $join->on('table1.id', '=', 'table2.model_id');
    });
```

**Error :** SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: JSON_EXTRACT

Answer (score 0):

`json` is a complicated data structure inside a database. You're not going to find one method that works across the four different database providers, as they all have their own proprietary way of dealing with json.

Laravel only uses the actual `json` datatype for MySQL and Postgres. For SQLite and MSSQL, the json is stored in a `varchar` field.

Laravel understands the "arrow" operator (`->`) for querying json fields in MySQL (5.7+) and Postgres. So, for MySQL and Postgres, your query would look like:

```
$query->select('table1.*')
    ->join('table2', function ($join) {
        return $join->on('table1.id', '=', 'table2.model_id');
    })
    ->where(function ($q) use ($locale) {
        return $q
            ->where('table2.attribute_data->title', '!=', "")
            ->where('table2.locale', '=', $locale);
    });
```

However, this will probably fail in SQLite and MSSQL, as they do not understand the arrow operator.

The only way to have this work across all database providers without changing the query would be to store the json data in a varchar in all databases, and then query the json string using the LIKE operator. This will be inefficient and probably error prone. Otherwise, you'll need to tailor your query to the database you're using.